Replacing Production Encrypted Column With Dummy Local Development Data
The company I work for is wanting to utilize SQL's built-in Always Encrypted features in order to encrypt certain table columns with sensitive column data. However, the software engineering team will not have access to the production encryption keys, and this is posing some problems with local development as we won't be able to decrypt these columns. We have spent days combing Google searches and have yet to find any guides/posts/etc of folks having similar issues. What would be the best way to go about replacing the encrypted columns with dummy data for local development to use?

We can't drop the CMK or CEK because they're being referenced by the columns
We can't alter the column or overwrite the column data as we don't have access to the key to decrypt it

EDIT:
I'm hoping to find an update-in-place solution to avoid any hassle from completely dropping the encrypted column and rebuilding it locally. I'm convinced there's some solution to force in randomized data for use in UAT/local development environments.

that depends much on the used database system


if developers are not allowed to have a copy of production data
meaning you don't want to decrypt the data even if you could

Then you'll have to generate dummy data.

Script the production database schema
generate dummy data
develop


Right... but any update scripts we try to run fail because we can't decrypt what's already there or encrypt what we're updating because we don't have access to the certificates/keys.

That's why you start your development environment with no data. If you have no data in the database you don't have to worry about trying to figure out how to decrypt it. And since you're scripting a new database from scratch, you can have it not enable always-on encryption.
